# ListView items shuffling when scrolling

Tags: android, listview

I have the following code in my adapter. Each item consists of two images, and under them a checkbox for each image. I want to display a list of these items, but when I scroll up and down it seems like the first and last items are the same. And then after a while the other items would be out of order as well. I've looked at other questions regarding this issue and I have not been able to find why my ListView items are shuffling after I scroll down and up.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View view = convertView;
    if(view == null){
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wheel_list_item, null);

        viewHolder.decisionNum = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.decisionNumText);
        viewHolder.leftWheel = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.leftWheel);
        viewHolder.rightWheel = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.rightWheel);
        viewHolder.leftCheckBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.leftCheckBox);
        viewHolder.rightCheckBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.rightCheckBox);
        viewHolder.wheelTuple = list.get(position);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.decisionNum.setText(Integer.toString(position + 1));

    viewHolder.leftCheckBox.setClickable(false);
    viewHolder.rightCheckBox.setClickable(false);

    viewHolder.leftWheel.setImageBitmap(new WheelView(context, viewHolder.wheelTuple.left).getBitmapReduced());
    viewHolder.rightWheel.setImageBitmap(new WheelView(context, viewHolder.wheelTuple.right).getBitmapReduced());

    int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("GREY", "color", context.getPackageName());
    int colorId=context.getResources().getColor(id);

    if(!viewHolder.wheelTuple.left.isChosen()){
        viewHolder.leftWheel.setColorFilter(colorId, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        viewHolder.rightCheckBox.setChecked(true);
    }
    else{
        viewHolder.rightWheel.setColorFilter(colorId, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        viewHolder.leftCheckBox.setChecked(true);
    }

    return view;
}

static class ViewHolder{
    TextView decisionNum;
    ImageView leftWheel;
    ImageView rightWheel;
    CheckBox leftCheckBox;
    CheckBox rightCheckBox;
    WheelListActivity.WheelTuple wheelTuple;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to  use below two functions,

```
@Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        if(searchList.size()==0){
            return 1;
        }
        return searchList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

And if your dataArrayList is having size 0, then remember to return 1 from getViewTypeCount(),Otherwise you will get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Refer the above code example.

Comment: Seems to work. To make sure I understand the code. getViewTypeCount() sets the number of ViewTypes. So in this case we just make each item in our list a different view type. getItemViewType() just returns the view type of the specific index. Because each index of the list is unique, the items can't be shuffled?

Comment: Yes items will not be shuffled. But be careful in case, if you are using listview for displaying images then you may get OutOfMemoryError as listview creates different view for each index but keeps only visible views in memory, In case of images you use Picasso to load your images.

Answer (score -1):

try and use code:

Addiding getview() in boolean array

```
        if (mCheckedState[position])
                     viewHolder.leftCheckBox.setChecked(true);
                else
                     viewHolder.leftCheckBox.setChecked(false);

        if (mCheckedState[position])
                    viewHolder.rightCheckBox.setChecked(true);
                else
                    viewHolder.rightCheckBox.setChecked(false);
```

Declare variable and set length:

boolean[] mCheckedState;

```
 public class Adapter_Sandesh extends BaseAdapter {

        Context context;
        boolean[] mCheckedState;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;


        public Adapter_Sandesh(FragmentActivity activity, String[] list_margdarshan) {
            context=activity;
            mCheckedState = new boolean[<your length>];


        }

       ...

       ...

       ...



     @Override
     public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
     View view = convertView;
     if(view == null){
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wheel_list_item, null);

        viewHolder.decisionNum = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.decisionNumText);
        viewHolder.leftWheel = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.leftWheel);
        viewHolder.rightWheel = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.rightWheel);
        viewHolder.leftCheckBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.leftCheckBox);
        viewHolder.rightCheckBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.rightCheckBox);
        viewHolder.wheelTuple = list.get(position);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.decisionNum.setText(Integer.toString(position + 1));

    viewHolder.leftCheckBox.setClickable(false);
    viewHolder.rightCheckBox.setClickable(false);



    if (mCheckedState[position])
                 viewHolder.leftCheckBox.setChecked(true);
            else
                 viewHolder.leftCheckBox.setChecked(false);

    if (mCheckedState[position])
                viewHolder.rightCheckBox.setChecked(true);
            else
                viewHolder.rightCheckBox.setChecked(false);


    viewHolder.leftWheel.setImageBitmap(new WheelView(context, viewHolder.wheelTuple.left).getBitmapReduced());
    viewHolder.rightWheel.setImageBitmap(new WheelView(context, viewHolder.wheelTuple.right).getBitmapReduced());

    int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("GREY", "color", context.getPackageName());
    int colorId=context.getResources().getColor(id);

    if(!viewHolder.wheelTuple.left.isChosen()){
        viewHolder.leftWheel.setColorFilter(colorId, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        viewHolder.rightCheckBox.setChecked(true);
    }
    else{
        viewHolder.rightWheel.setColorFilter(colorId, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        viewHolder.leftCheckBox.setChecked(true);
    }

    return view;
}

static class ViewHolder{
    TextView decisionNum;
    ImageView leftWheel;
    ImageView rightWheel;
    CheckBox leftCheckBox;
    CheckBox rightCheckBox;
    WheelListActivity.WheelTuple wheelTuple;
}
}
```